# Inner join in mysql, syntax error, regarding php query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
       $threadID=$_GET['threadID'];

            $result=mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM threads AS Threads
            INNER JOIN users AS Users ON Threads.user_id=Users.user_id 
            WHERE thread_id='$threadID' LIMIT 1
            ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I get this:

> u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11' at
>   line 3

I wrote many inner joins before. Why is my syntax wrong near the end of the query

updated: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12' LIMIT 1' at line 3

Comment: Can you echo the complete query (or at least the value of $threadID)? It looks like $threadID might be set to `'11` (with a leading single-quote) for some reason.

Comment: it says exactly like this - `"u have.."`?

Comment: @Col: must be Oracle's new 'MySQL, teenager edition'. Comes in 12 hip colors and all output converted into txt/l33t.

Comment: lol..no you have. do i put echo on the result..

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12' LIMIT 1' at line 3

Comment: yup ..when i echo #threadID..it gives soemthing like '14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your query is WIDE open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Second, to figure out why you get the syntax error, make the query building phase separate from the actual query call:

```
$sql = "SELECT ....";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(...);
```

This way you can see the entire query. MySQL's error messages only report the portion of the query from where it thinks the error is onwards, but sometimes it decides wrong and elminates the actual relevant part where th error is... so... examine the ENTIRE query.

Comment: Up-vote for mentioning SQL injection. It's easy to avoid, but easy to ignore.

Comment: What do you want me to check? whether the request came from the previous page. I do need to send the threadID by GET.. although I could do it by post too.. it is convenient to send some ids by get..

Comment: It's not that you're getting some value from _GET. It's that you're stuffing that value directly into your query string without any kind of sanitization. Consider what happens if someone passed in this query string: `1 OR 1=1`. That turns the query into `... WHERE thread_id=1 OR 1=1` and now they're retrieving all records in the table. This doesn't work with MySQL in PHP anymore, but consider the dangers of this query string: `1; DROP TABLE USERS`.

Comment: And as for your update, show us the actual SQL query string. the error message is useless for diagnosis without seeing what caused the error in the first place.

Comment: Thanks the error is gone.why am I open to sql injection?!? so what if I put the threadID in the url.. isnt the use of cookies and sessions make you open to sql injections

Comment: @Matrix001 This doesn't answer your primary question, but it will help stop SQL Injection. Since the 'threadID' query string parameter could be set to anything (like `1'; DROP TABLE threads; --`, for example), you should use prepared statements with parameters. In PHP this is supported through [MySQLi](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/12442-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: why cant I check on the GET[]   is_number() ..or do  this: or do you want me to do this @DECLARE ThreadId; SET ThreadId="$threadID"?

Comment: Matrix: you HAVE to sanitize user input before inserting it into an SQL string. Usually that's done with mysql_real_escape_string(). In your case, since it seems strict mode is on, you'd have to do eliminate the quotes around the value in the query, and force it to be an int in PHP via `$threadID = intval($_GET['threadID']);`

Comment: okay, I will do so. i will remember that function and I have already a function that sanitizes input.

Comment: Don't roll your own sanitization functions. Use m_r_e_s(). It's specifically designed for (and provided by) mysql. Anything else, which DOESN'T use m_r_e_s() is going to miss some edge case that'd still allow an attack to occur.

Comment: I use this function in addition to that function above:    function SanitizeString($var)
   {
    $var=stripslashes($var);
    $var=htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $var=strip_tags($var);
    $var=trim($var);
    return $var;
   }

Comment: @Matrix001 don't listen to him, this is not truth. You don't have to "sanitize" user input. You have to format your data according to SQL rules. ALWAYS. No matter if it's user input or not. And it's not a sanitizing but merely a formatting. and mysql_real_escape_string() doesn't "sanitize" anything as well.

Comment: so should I write the int like this:  WHERE thread_id='$threadID' LIMIT 1 or without the ''

Comment: @Matrix001 yes. And don't forget to cast this variable to the int type. **this is obligatory.** like using mysql_real_escape_string for the quoted strings, casting numeric values to the proper type is a must and should never be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

ah, may be I know the answer.
There is a thing in mysql, i believe, called `"strict mode"` or something, which being too picky about data types.

Try to make your query like this

```
   $id  = (int)$_GET['threadID']; 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM threads t INNER JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.user_id  
           WHERE thread_id=$id LIMIT 1"; 
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
```

Comment: hmm..interesting syntax near the end.. thank you for that line..I will use it from now on

Answer (score 0):

Why not join your query in this fashion:

```
$threadID = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['threadID'] ); // Get some cleanup in there...

$result=mysql_query("SELECT threads.*, users.*
FROM threads, users 
WHERE threads.user_id = users.user_id 
AND threads.thread_id = '$threadID' 
LIMIT 1
") or die( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: lol..perhaps it means the same thing and a bit shorter. I am thinking of using this syntax which is shortest ... USING(users.user_id),, interesting syntax, you have shown